# VB.NET Custom Drawn Control Memory Usage

Tags: vb.net

I have a lot of custom controls that change colour when the mouse hovers over them. Unfortunately, the memory usage sky rockets with repeated hovers. It starts off at about 14mb and shoots up to 100mb after quickly hovering over it for a few times.

Some code is shown below, this is the generation, drawing and invalidating of control. I believe the memory issue will lie in here somewhere. The memory used only seems to get released when the application is minimized.

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer Or ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, True)
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

    Dim BorderColour As Color = ColourSchemes.GetLighterColourFromTheme
    Dim FillColour As Color = ColourSchemes.GetNormalColourFromTheme
    Dim CheckFillColour As Color = ColourSchemes.GetNormalColourFromTheme(ColourSchemes.HiddenTheme.SilverInterface)
    Dim OutlineCheckColour As Color = ColourSchemes.GetNormalColourFromTheme


    Dim InnerRect As New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), New Size(Me.Width - 1, Me.Height - 1))

    If CTRLRule = CTRLStyle.Classic Or CTRLRule = CTRLStyle.ClassicWithColour Then
        'CLASSIC STYLE

        Dim XY As Integer = 0

        If CTRLBoxSize = 0 Then
            XY = CalculateCheckSquare()
        Else
            XY = CTRLBoxSize
        End If

        Dim CheckRect As New Rectangle(New Point(5, ((Me.Height - XY + 2)) / 2), New Size(XY - 4, XY - 4))

        Dim TextHeight As Integer = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text, Font).Height

        Dim TextArea As New Rectangle(New Point(5 + XY + 5, (Me.Height - TextHeight) / 2), New Size(Me.Width - (7 + XY), TextHeight))

        If CTRLRule = CTRLStyle.Classic Then

            Select Case Switcher
                Case StyleSwitcher.Normal
                    OutlineCheckColour = ColourSchemes.GetNormalColourFromTheme(ColourSchemes.HiddenTheme.SilverInterface)
                    CheckFillColour = ColourSchemes.GetNormalColourFromTheme(ColourSchemes.HiddenTheme.SilverInterface)
                Case StyleSwitcher.Rollover
                    OutlineCheckColour = ColourSchemes.GetLighterColourFromStyle(ColourStyle)
                    CheckFillColour = ColourSchemes.GetLighterColourFromStyle(ColourStyle)
                    If Checked = True Then
                        OutlineCheckColour = ColourSchemes.GetNormalColourFromStyle(ColourStyle)
                        CheckFillColour = ColourSchemes.GetNormalColourFromStyle(ColourStyle)
                    End If
                Case StyleSwitcher.Depressed
                    OutlineCheckColour = ColourSchemes.GetDarkerColourFromStyle(ColourStyle)
                    CheckFillColour = ColourSchemes.GetDarkerColourFromStyle(ColourStyle)
            End Select

        Else

            Select Case Switcher
                Case StyleSwitcher.Normal
                    OutlineCheckColour = ColourSchemes.GetNormalColourFromTheme(ColourSchemes.HiddenTheme.SilverInterface)
                Case StyleSwitcher.Rollover
                    OutlineCheckColour = ColourSchemes.GetLighterColourFromStyle(ColourStyle)
                Case StyleSwitcher.Depressed
                    OutlineCheckColour = ColourSchemes.GetDarkerColourFromStyle(ColourStyle)
            End Select

            If Checked = True Then
                BorderColour = ColourSchemes.GetNormalColourFromStyle(ColourStyle)
                CheckFillColour = ColourSchemes.GetNormalColourFromStyle(ColourStyle)
                OutlineCheckColour = ColourSchemes.GetNormalColourFromStyle(ColourStyle)
            End If

            CheckFillColour = OutlineCheckColour

        End If

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(FillColour), InnerRect)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(BorderColour), InnerRect)
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(New Pen(OutlineCheckColour, 2), CheckRect)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, New SolidBrush(ColourSchemes.GetFontColourFromTheme), TextArea, New StringFormat With {.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center, .Alignment = StringAlignment.Near})

        If Checked = True Then
            Dim TSize As Integer = (CheckRect.Width / 6) 'WANT INNERDS TO FILL 3/4
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(CheckFillColour), New Rectangle(New Point(CheckRect.X + TSize, CheckRect.Y + TSize), New Size(CheckRect.Width - (TSize * 2), CheckRect.Height - (TSize * 2))))
        End If

    Else
        'LIGHT STYLE

        Dim LightPen As Color = ColourSchemes.GetLighterColourFromTheme
        Dim LightPen2 As Color
        Dim TextColour As Color = ColourSchemes.GetFontColourFromTheme

        If CTRLRule = CTRLStyle.Light Then
            LightPen2 = ColourSchemes.GetLighterColourFromTheme
        Else
            LightPen2 = ColourSchemes.GetNormalColourFromStyle(ColourStyle)
            If Me.Checked = True Then
                TextColour = ColourSchemes.GetNormalColourFromStyle(ColourStyle)
            End If
        End If

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(ColourSchemes.GetDarkerColourFromTheme, 3), New Point(0, Me.Height - 1), New Point(Me.Width, Me.Height - 1))

        Dim ArrowH As Integer = Me.Height - ((Me.Height - 8) / 2)

        If Me.Checked = True Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(LightPen2, 2), New Point(Me.Width - 30, Convert.ToSingle(ArrowH)), New Point(Me.Width - 20, Convert.ToSingle(ArrowH - 8)))
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(LightPen2, 2), New Point(Me.Width - 10, Convert.ToSingle(ArrowH)), New Point(Me.Width - 20, Convert.ToSingle(ArrowH - 8)))
        Else
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(LightPen, 2), New Point(Me.Width - 20, Convert.ToSingle(ArrowH)), New Point(Me.Width - 30, Convert.ToSingle(ArrowH - 8)))
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(LightPen, 2), New Point(Me.Width - 20, Convert.ToSingle(ArrowH)), New Point(Me.Width - 10, Convert.ToSingle(ArrowH - 8)))
        End If

        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, New SolidBrush(TextColour), InnerRect, New StringFormat With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near, .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center})

    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeave(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseLeave(e)
    Switcher = StyleSwitcher.Normal
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseEnter(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseEnter(e)
    Switcher = StyleSwitcher.Rollover
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

EDIT: Following @Hans Passant comment, I have changed the code around to make use of "using" statements. However, this seems to have no effect in runtime. The changed code is shown below (providing I interpreted the comment correctly)

```
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(FillColour), InnerRect)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(BorderColour), InnerRect)
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(New Pen(OutlineCheckColour, 2), CheckRect)

        Using Brush As New SolidBrush(FillColour)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush, InnerRect)
        End Using

        Using Pen As New Pen(BorderColour, 1)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pen, InnerRect)
            Pen.Color = OutlineCheckColour
            Pen.Width = 2
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pen, CheckRect)
        End Using
```

Comment: The Pen and SolidBrush classes implement IDisposable.  You should be using the *Using* statement in your code to ensure these objects get disposed.  You can easily see this in Task Manager, View + Select Columns and tick GDI Objects.  It should be steadily rising for your app.  It does go down, eventually.

Comment: @HansPassant I've modified the code, however, it hasnt had much effect on the actualy memory usage in task mananger. The GDI/USER objects tabs were created and disposed of correctly to start with

Comment: Well, you haven't posted anything that anybody else can try.  Use a decent memory profiler to discover more.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with unmanaged memory. It also happens to be nothing to do with the control itself, rather the form that its hosted on. I also run a customized form, when I copied all controls onto a standard form and repeated the test, there was only a minor memory increase (of about 50kb per second) as opposed to the metro form where the increase was anywhere between 3mb - 10mb per second.